# Mysql between query for two date is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table that contain two datetime field. So when I going to search anything betwwn two dates then it do not show exact result. It suffering me more when I want to see only one day search result. My code is

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE production_date BETWEEN $a AND $b
```

Comment: If you want to see one day of data why not just select from that one day?

Comment: Yep, that's the correct basic syntax. Show the values for `$a` and `$b`, your expected results, and the actual results.

Comment: @JayBlanchard my search panel contain two datepicker.

Comment: Which are the values of $a and $b ?

Comment: $a='2014-05-04', $b='2014-05-02'. Want to see all result for 2,3,4 but only get the result of 2014-05-03. @Sammitch

Comment: try by this. $sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE production_date BETWEEN " . "'" . $a . "'" . " AND " . "'" .$b ."'";

Comment: or try by this. DATE(your_date_var) >= '2014-05-03' AND DATE(your_date_var) <= 2014-05-04. Both are working for me.

Comment: @user3680687 , you chose the wrong answer as correct.

Comment: @edduvs , That answer solved my problem. Also you are correct and I am not allowed to accept multiple answer. My vote may be be goes to wrong answer from your side but not for me. I am absolute a novice programmer. So I do not have the ability to justify the quality of answer. :(

Comment: @user3680687 the easier way is not always the best way. This community strives to gives you the best solution for your problems, of course there are many solutions, but you as question author should choose the best solution, because correct ones may be more, and since new users come everyday, they'll pick the correct answer instead picking the best solution. You can press again on that "correct answer" green icon and choose the best solution as the right answer. Hope new users will see the votes there. Regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using datetime as the type for your field. Change it to only date and it will works fine!

Or you can use '2014-05-27 00:00:00' as start date and '2014-05-28 23:59:59' as your end date. Means add some extra string with your variable.

Comment: Changing the schema to accommodate one query is an awful idea.

Comment: Then see my other option. But if anyone do not need datetime then why not use only date? @Sammitch

Comment: Your 'other option' is sane, but your initial suggestion to change the schema is utterly insane. You cannot judge the schema design by looking at *one* query and suggest completely changing a data type like that.

Comment: There's no need to change the sql structure since I answered with a simple caster to `date()`, but the author chose this as correct, I'm a little bit surprised.

Comment: @MdRiadHossain, carry on. It is time to ask & answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to `CAST` your production_date as `DATE` like this, otherwise `BETWEEN` will get exclusive instead inclusive.

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE DATE(production_date) BETWEEN $a AND $b
```

I'm not sure if your column has a time component, truncate it out with `DATE(column)` but if it does, this should do the trick.